# resize of image width but not height and quality will be remain

Tags: adobe-photoshop

how can i resize line image width but height will be same and quality will be remain as it seen through Photoshop is it possible

[image]

Comment: Hi Anubhav, What have you tried and why didn't that work?

Comment: i have a line of 320px i want it 200px but height must be same can but quality will be remain how in photoshop

Comment: I understand what you want to do but have you tried anything to resize the line yourself? You could transform the line, you could just re-create the line with rounded rectangle tool.

Comment: no option by photoshop

Comment: What do you mean "no option by photoshop"? I explained 2 methods of shortening the line in Photoshop in my last comment. Please try something and your chances for a good answer increase.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26888/discussion-between-anubhav-and-andrewh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## You can use the "Free Transform" command (no round corners)

Simply select the layer where your line is, and press "command + T" on your keyboard (or Control + T on pc)

You can also right-click on your shape (while having the layer selected where it is) and you'll see the command Free Transform in the menu too.

[image: Fres Transform]

**Then you'll see some handles appearing.

Zoom in and you'll see there's an handle in the middle that isn't in a corner; it's hard to see on small lines like yours if you don't zoom the image.**

**It's the one you need to click and drag to the left or right** to resize your line without losing quality, and without increasing the thickness of the line. If you click on the handles on the corner, they will transform your line vertically and horizontally.

[image: Free Transform horizontally]

---

## You can do a simple "cut and duplicate" (round corners)

Delete a middle part of line.

[image: cut line]

Use the "move tool" and move one of the end closer the the center of your line.

[image: move selection]

Use the "Rectangle Marquee Tool" (rectangle selection), select a middle part of your line and duplicate it. Hold "shift + alt + command" to duplicate your selection. Duplicate many times if needed.

Note: This can create jagged lines because of the anti-aliasing. In this case, use free transform as mentioned above instead of duplicate to join it with the end of your line.

[image: duplicate]

Comment: but i want rounded corner in both side

Comment: @Anubhav Edited. In return, could you please edit your question as well to mention you want to 1) Resize smaller and 2) keep the corners? It's not that obvious your line has corners at the size of your image.